# finding symbols such as music note with php pregmatch

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to write an app that is capable of finding a music note like this ♫ in a body of text. I know I need to use pregmatch in PHP but I have no idea how to write the expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the [`u` pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), you can match Unicode ranges.

```
$str = '♪ ♩ abc ♫ def ♫ ♬';
preg_match_all('~[\x{2669}-\x{266F}]~u', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This matches the following characters:

```
♩  ‎2669  QUARTER NOTE
♪  ‎266A  EIGHTH NOTE
♫  ‎266B  BEAMED EIGHTH NOTES
♬  ‎266C  BEAMED SIXTEENTH NOTES
♭  ‎266D  MUSIC FLAT SIGN
♮  ‎266E  MUSIC NATURAL SIGN
♯  ‎266F  MUSIC SHARP SIGN
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is same with find other string.

```
preg_match_all('/♫/', 'abc ♫ ddd', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general this is way preg_match works in php is

```
 if ( preg_match("/Find this string/", "From this string") )     {
      echo "A match was found.";
 } else {
      echo "A match was not found.";
 }
```

Finding musical note might not be a trivial task, but if the string you are searching contains only numbers and letters you might try this to help you out.

```
preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", $string_you_are_searching_from);
```

I hope this helps.